# Upload document from local machine to server without using file input type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

We are trying to upload a document from our local machine to server. We know that .NET browse control can be used for this but our requirement is to just have a button and call that as "Save Document". On click we know the path and also the document name, all we need to do is search the document in local machine (inside temp folder) and if the document is available then pick it and save it to our APP data folder on the server.

it's easy to achieve this using .NET borwse control but not sure how to do that same using normal button?

Comment: How do you want the button to work? On click it loads the file specified in a textbox or some other way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.  All the File/Open dialog does is return a path, so why don't you just substitute whatever path you want, and do the same thing that you did after the File/Dialog returned?  What does "without using file input type" mean?

Comment: I am not using a file open control here.. all i have is a button

Comment: On Button Click --> I need to search the temp directory on users machine and look for a document (I have the doc name with me) If the document is available in the users temp directory then pick the document from there and save it to APP data folder

Comment: Not possible. For security, your site is only given access to file(s) explicitly specified by the user (using the file input). You cannot simply pick a file yourself from the user's computer, and it's a good thing you can't. Good lord, every other site on the internet would be trying to steal sensitive files from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To find a file in a folder:

```
FileInfo file = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\folder")
                         .FirstOrDefault(f => f.name = whatever);
```

To copy file:

```
File.Copy(file.FullName, targetPath, true);
```

Comment: this will work only if you are testing in local machine. once you deploy the code in server this will look for (@"c:\folder")
in the server not in users machine. I need to pick the document from users temp directory not from server temp directory.

Comment: Then you need to store the temp directory in a cookie, or something like that.  Unfortunately, Javascript is a sandboxed language, so you're not going to be able to scan the hard drive on the client unless you have some native application running there, perhaps a Java applet.  I suggest you write a Java applet to do this.  The user will have to approve the applet, acknowledging that it's OK to run it on their machine.